# Android Login with Facebook and Spring Social using Existing User Access Token

Tags: android, spring, facebook, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Here's what I currently have:

Android app that use Facebook SDK for authentication, and I get from Facebook userId and token, and I store that info in database in my Spring app, but I want for Spring app to check with Facebook is that token valid and secure my endpoints.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security